# How to debug failing GraphQL queries in "Gatsby Build" process?

Tags: gatsby

My  GraphQL service provider is asking for exact GraphQL CURL request when I get 500 errors from their server during build process. Is there any way to debug and print more information about these curl requests?

Comment: https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/debugging/

Comment: Terrible reply.  Gatsby provides no help or clue with this error.
`UNHANDLED REJECTION Cannot read property 'match' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'match' of undefined`